# Symfony Api Platform Filtering Null Values

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

My entity and table is below. As you can see, I have parent column with ManyToOne relationship in table.
Child rows are filtering using parent column. I want to get parent rows or null parent values. How can I do this in Symfony APi Platform?

I have tried using custom query extension. But it applies where condition in any case.

```
# Table uyap_type
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parent_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| code      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\NumericFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\UyapTypeRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get", "post"},
 *     itemOperations={"get", "put", "delete"}
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(NumericFilter::class, properties={"parent.id"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UyapTypeRepository::class)
 */
class UyapType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=UyapType::class)
     */
    private $parent;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getParent(): ?self
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function setParent(?self $parent): self
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$repository->findBy(
    ['parent' => null]
);
```

You can configure itemOperations if you want to add a route with a controller

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#using-serialization-groups

Comment: I think itemOperations custom is the best way too.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. @Jo0kker